# Write seven natural number written in circle so that in any pair of neighbours, one divides the other.

Tags: number-theory

Seven natural numbers are written in circle. It is known that in each pair of two adjacent numbers, one of them divides the other.

$$\begin{matrix}
&&a_{1} \\ &\nearrow && \searrow \\
a_{7}&&&&a_{2}\\ \uparrow&&&& \downarrow\\ a_{6}&&&&a_{3} && \\ &\nwarrow  &&\swarrow\\ &&a_{5}\leftarrow a_4 
\end{matrix}
$$
Show that there are two non-adjacent numbers with the same property, this is, one of them divides the other.

Comment: What is a neighborhood number

Comment: @StellaBiderman do you understand now?

Comment: So, two adjacent numbers?

Comment: Yes, if you prefer to say in this way.

Comment: Could you use the transitivity of division to prove this easily? If a divides b and b divides c then a divides c kind of idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the numbers in a circle based on adjacency, and draw arrows going clockwise between them like in the picture above.

Assign each arrow a number, $-1$ or $1$, with $-1$ meaning that the division goes against the direction of the arrows (i.e. if $a_1|a_7$ or if $a_5|a_4$) and a $1$ if it goes in the same direction (i.e. if $a_7|a_1$ or if $a_4|a_5$). In the case that the numbers are equal, assign both $-1$ and $1$.

Since "divides" is a transitive relation ($a|b,b|c\Rightarrow a|c$) this problem is equivalent to asking if two consecutive arrows have the same number assigned to them. Since there are an odd number of arrows, this is guaranteed to happen.

Comment: Of course, it is possible that $a_1=a_2$, so there isn't a direction, but that case can be handled easily.

Comment: Sure! Assign both $-1$ and $1$. I added that

Comment: Why the arrows must be consecutive? Could occur that $a_{1}|a_{5}$? In this case you solution is wrong?

Comment: You drew the diagram with numbers in order as you follow the arrows so I referred to them as such. You can always relabel the numbers so that it looks like it does in your diagram, with no arrow between $a_1$ and $a_5$.

Comment: I don't know what problem you're having. I made a small edit, but I don't understand why you're confused

Comment: I think I understood. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! don't forget to accept the answer so that the problem gets marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

Assume wlog $a_1|a_2$. Notice that you have to avoid $a|b|c$ or you get $a|c$ which are not adjacent. Which is the relation between $a_2$ and $a_3$? It can't be $a_2 | a_3$ or you stick in the $abc$ situation, so $a_3|a_2$. Keep evaluating this way you get
$a_1 | a_2, a_3 | a_2, a_3 | a_4, a_5 | a_4, a_5 | a_6, a_7 | a_6, a_7 | a_1 $. But now $a_7 | a_1 | a_2$.